# Logstash removing BOM

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have logstash in reading log files which is actually text document. I have come across with BOM (Byte of Mark) problem at the very first line of records. How can I get rid of it?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add more details? What is exactly the problem (in term of expected vs real result)? Configuration and example input & output is also welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39699978/229949 seems to be the answer

Answer (score 1):

Until [logstash-input-file](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file) would trim BOM mark by itself (which it does not do as of v4.1.10), you could add `mutate` filter to remove it.

```
filter {
    mutate {
        # Trim BOM mark
        gsub => [
            "message", "^\xEF\xBB\xBF", ""
        ]
    }
}
```